# Selenium Webdriver - Drag and drop does not work

Tags: java, selenium, drag-and-drop

I know there are several posts about this issue. Tried almost all the solutions in my project but unable to make drag and drop work. I am using following code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebElement dragableElement = 
driver.findElement(By.className("dragElement"));
WebElement dropableContainer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*
[@id='contentCollection_xyz']"));

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(dragableElement)
   .moveToElement(dropableContainer)
   .release(dropableContainer)
   .build();
dragAndDrop.perform();
```

This drops my dragable element just before dropable container.

Comment: You might want to dedicate a bit of time to properly format your question. Please, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which describes your issue, add more details on your problem so that we have some starting point / context to work with

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten drag and drop to work with selenium, this is a poorly worded question though. We need more details, and stack overflow is not the place to find someone to "share your screen with".